# How to get the full Basic Math Assist palette

Tags: palettes

I find that in the latest version of Mma and Windows the Basic Math Assist palette cuts off all the useful functions (see image below). The only fix I have found is to close the tiny window and click on Palettes/Basic Math Assist. How do I directly expand the
original Palette?
[image]

Comment: Cant you just resize the window or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: No, I can't just resize the window, no matter where I hover, click, and/or drag: very frustrating!

Comment: On my system, how much of the pallet I can get in the window depends on the zoom level.  By reducing it to 75%, I can get the calculator section and the basic commands section to display without scrolling, and the font size is still quite readable. This is on a 1920x1280 display. Maybe with a really big display one could expand all the sections and still not need to scroll. I also cannot resize the window, but it occupies almost the full vertical screen.

Comment: On my system Win10, Mma 12.0.0.0 and display 1920x1080 the pallet is visible almost completely at 100% magnification. You stated the display 1920x1280. May it be the problem?